# Particles in fluid-simulation are falling through Object

Tags: fluid-simulation

I made a fountain in Blender. The fluid simulation looks like it works, but in the last part of the Fountain it falls through it.

[image]

I had a similar problem few weeks ago and I solved it by increasing the Timesteps minimum and maximum in the Domain settings.
But here it does not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your normals and make sure your obstacle is thick enough compared to your simulation resolution (it must be at least thick enough to contain a ‘cell’ width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the bottom is thick enough, or increase the resolution of the domain. You might also want to enable "fractional obstacles" because I see that some of the fluid is sticking to the surface of the fountain.

Comment: Heyy, thanks!
The last basin had no 3D floor. Just the ring around it was effected by the "solidify-modifier". So after adding thickness to it, all Particles stopped falling through.

I will try the "fractional obstacles" option out. Thanks for this tipp:)


Have a nice day!